# JS Can't increase global variable within function

Tags: javascript, html

Lets say I have Javascript and HTML code as below:

```js
var x = 1

function increase() {
    x += 1
    console.log(x)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="increase()">Click</button>
```

When I click the button `x` increases to 2 but won't increase any further. Why does `x` not become 2,3,4... and how can I make `x` continue to increase?

## Situation

So apparently my minimal example works so I thought I would include the situation where I am using this logic and where it is not working:

JS:

```
var x = 1
var y = 1

function increase(number) {
    number += 1
    console.log(number)
}
```

```
<button onclick="increase(x)">Increase x</button>
<button onclick="increase(y)">Increase y</button>
```

I expect my console to display:

```
2
3
4
5
```

But it displays:

```
2
2
2
2
```

I really don't understand how the above example works and my situation doesn't

## Clarification

To clarify, I want to pass various variables into the function (as above), so while many of the answers provided work (I have upvoted them) they do not work in my context, I should have stated this earlier on..

Comment: I tried you code and it worked. Are you sure that it's stuck in 2?

Comment: If I added code for the actual situation where I am using this would it help? This does not work in the actual situation where I am applying it..

Comment: There's likely a larger contextual issue not revealed in the snippet. You sure the page isn't reloading?

Comment: The source code you have provided appears to be working just fine [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/d9fwv5y8/) Open your browser console and check for errors, if you see any please update your question and include the error details.

Comment: I suspect that you may very well have another function that wants a local `x` but you forgot to declare it.

Comment: You keep passing in 1.

Comment: @DaveNewton I thought as much, so how would I go about permanently increase `x` by 1?

Comment: @AlexHawking you could use `x++;` which will increase the integer by 1. [**JsFiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/pwt08cx4/)

Comment: Just use the first version! It works!

Comment: I have edited my answer to clarify some things about the context of where I am using this

Comment: what exactly does `y` do in here?

Comment: @HishamBawa I basically want to make a function that permanently increases variables passed into it by 1, the changes made to these variables need to be global

Comment: so lets say when you start it, the number is 1. when you press x, it becomes 2. then if you press y it should be 3 or does a different number become 2?

Comment: The variables should increase differently, you press x twice x = 3. You price y once, y becomes 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your last edit, where you are incrementing multiple variables independently, the problem space changes significantly, rendering most of the answers inapplicable.

It is important to provide an example sufficient to reproduce the problem.

Regardless, there are many ways to achieve your desired outcome where, given

```
var x = 1
var y = 1
```

and given

```
<button onclick="increase(x)">Increase x</button>
<button onclick="increase(y)">Increase y</button>
```

`x` and `y` are incremented by their respective button.

A relatively ugly solution:

Given that `x` and `y` are global variables, and given that all global variables in JavaScript are properties of the JavaScript global object (`window` in browsers), you can write

```js
"use strict";
var x = 1;
var y = 1;

function increase(globalName) {
  window[globalName] += 1;

  console.log(window[globalName]);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="increase('x')">Increase x</button>
<button onclick="increase('y')">Increase y</button>
```

Now we should not in fact be creating all of these global variables. Especially if they have relatively terse, commonly used names like `increase` or `x` you will run into collisions before you know it, even within your own code.

If you are going to use global variables at all, you should at most *one* for your entire application. Everything that was previously a discretely global variable, then becomes a property of that global application object.

Answer (score 2):

In short, try this:

```js
var x = 1

function increase(number) {
    number += 1

    // Also update x
    x = number;
    console.log(number)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="increase(x)">Increase</button>
```

Your problem is that you're not updating `x` when the button is clicked. Therefore `x` is initialized to `1` and onclick of the button it's passed to `increase` which then increments and logs `number` but never updates `x`, so successive calls to `increase` continue using the original value of `x`, 1.

Here's a [minimal example](https://jsbin.com/wicufetiwe/edit?html,js,console,output).

Answer (score 1):

because the `number` in the function is a separate variable from the `x` outside the function. The variable is only passing a copy of itself to the function.

```
var x = 1;
    x += 1 // x = 2 here;

function increase( number ) {
    number += 1
    console.log(x)
    console.log(number)
}

increase(x)
console.log(x)
```

if we were to return a value from the function and assign it to the variable, we would have a different situation

```
var x = 1;

function increase( number ) {
    number += 1
    return number;
}

x = increase(x)
console.log(x)
```

Comment: Indeed correct. But since his `function` is an event handler called by the dom, `return` isn't the way to go. The original approach, using closures, is the way to go.

Comment: Yup, very nice answer @AluanHaddad ( i imagine i'll delete this shortly but wanted to leave it up long enough for you to see that i appreciated our correspondence :) )

Comment: Thank you. I likewise appreciate it. Your answer here contains helpful information that is pertinent to the question. I focused on specifically resolving his immediate issue, but this answer is more educational. I would leave it up.

Comment: Thanks @AluanHaddad i'll do that. & I'll give some thought to improving it ( i tend to use oop patterns and was having a difficult time explaining it without going off on a tangent )

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```js
var x = 1

function increase(number) {
    
    number = ++x
    console.log(number)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="increase(x)">Increase</button>
```

Comment: That works, but what is the point of it? The parameter is useless.

Answer (score 0):

It's the notorious pass by reference or pass by value argue.
[Here's a link to explain this situation](https://jsfiddle.net/yxhxtx/uz2vma78/)

So your situation is that `number` as a local scope variable copies the value of `x` (which you have passed in), so now `number = 1`, after `number += 1`, `number = 2`, then `console.log()` outputs 2.

then onclick function triggered again, the local function scope variable `number` doesn't keep a reference, so it again copies value from the value of variable `x`(which again value doesn't change), and then repeats the above process again.

[Here's a JS fiddle snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/yxhxtx/uz2vma78/)

```js
var x = { number: 1 };
var y = { number: 1 };

function increase(object) {
  object.number++;
  document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = x.number;
  document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = y.number;
}

console.log(x);
console.log(y);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <button onclick="increase(x)">Increase X</button>
      <span id="x"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button onclick="increase(y)">Increase Y</button>
      <span id="y"></span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So is there a solution for this?

Comment: I am just thinking it out loud, say `xObject = { name: 'x', numberClicks: 1}` `yObject = { name: 'y', numberClicks: 1}`, then pass xObject, yObject into the function and then `xObject.numberClicks += 1` or `yObject.numberClicks += 1`, the the state has been saved into xObject or yObject